# Update attched sqlite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to update a sqlite db table from another database.
I used the below code to copy it but I can't make it update whenever the single.sqlite db has new rows.

Here is what I have:

```
$db = new SQLite3("db/multi_db.db");
// copy/clone single.sqlite to multi_db.db
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'db/single.sqlite' AS single");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE "vars" AS SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
// update multi_db with new rows from single.sqlite
$db->exec('UPDATE TABLE "vars" SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
```

I tried different ways to update, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: PS: The creation an copy of the new bd works great, just that the update never happens when the single.sqlite db has new rows

Comment: Do you also have the problem if you try via SQLite commandline tool, instead of via code? I.e. can you make a pure SQLite [mcve]?

Comment: This is not a valid [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html). Check for errors. Anyway, how do you distinguish between new and other rows?

Comment: @CL. can you please be more specific. I looked into the documentation and can't see where the error is. Thanks

Comment: @CL. rowid should be a way to distinguish between new and other rows

Comment: But your queries do not check the rowid? Anway, please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UPDATE command is not valid.

You can use:

```
$db->exec('INSERT INTO vars SELECT * FROM single.vars');
```

But notice that if there are already rows with the same rowid in the destination table then collision can occur. To replace the values on the table you can use:

```
$db->exec('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO vars SELECT * FROM single.vars');
```

Comment: Thanks @Bernardo Ramos . Works perfect. How about the difference in performance between INSERT OR REPLACE and DROP TABLE IF EXISTS and recreate it each time?

Comment: So, from performance point of view, what's the best way. To first drop the table and and create it OR use the INSERT OR REPLACE INTO option? What option is faster?

Comment: To be more specific, what's the best way to do it from performance stand point:
1. Version1:
$db = new SQLite3("db/multi_db.db");
$db->exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vars");
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'db/single.sqlite' AS single");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE "vars" AS SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
OR
2. Version2:
`$db = new SQLite3("db/multi_db.db");
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'db/single.sqlite' AS single");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE "vars" AS SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
$db->exec('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO vars SELECT * FROM single.vars');`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've spelled your table incorrectly. I'm assuming that it should be `single."vars"`, not `single."vras"`.

```
$db = new SQLite3("db/multi_db.db");
// copy/clone single.sqlite to multi_db.db
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'db/single.sqlite' AS single");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE "vars" AS SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
// update multi_db with new rows from single.sqlite
$db->exec('UPDATE TABLE "vars" SELECT * FROM single."vars"');
```

Comment: was just for example. Real table is correct spelled. I updated main thread